How can I deserialize map from Firebase Firestore?
My FirebaseFirestore looks like the below image

My code snipped for deserialization is as below:
class StripeProductPlan extends Equatable {
  final DocumentReference selfRef;

  final Map<String, String> metaData;
  final String name;
  final String? role;
  final String? taxCode;

  const StripeProductPlan({
    required this.selfRef,
    required this.metaData,
    required this.name,
    this.role,
    this.taxCode,
  });

 factory StripeProductPlan.fromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data()!;
    return StripeProductPlan(
      metaData: data['metadata'] as Map<String, String>, //Edited
      selfRef: snapshot.reference,
      name: data['name'] as String,
      role: data['role'] as String? ?? '',
      taxCode: data['taxCode'] as String? ?? '',
    );
  }

Everything else works, except for the metaData deserialization. How do I fix this?

I see in your screenshot:

That your Map field is called medatadata while in your class is called metaData, which is not correct. The field names must match. See the difference, the field in the database starts with a lowercase letter d while in the class starts with the capital letter D.
To solve thisin the simplest way possible, please change the name of the field in the class to match the one in the database:
class StripeProductPlan extends Equatable {
  final DocumentReference selfRef;

  final Map<String, String> metadata; //
  final String name;
  final String? role;
  final String? taxCode;

  //...

}


I fixed that, but I am still getting error for the same.

Please edit your question and add the changes you made. Please make sure to change the name in every place it exists.

To deserialize the metadata from your Firestore document into a Dart class, you can define a Dart model class that matches the structure of your Firestore document. Based on the image you provided, here is an example of how to define a Dart class and implement deserialization:
class Metadata {
 final bool isTestingPlan;
  final int maxParticipants;
  final String orderIdx;
  final String productId;

  Metadata({
    required this.isTestingPlan,
    required this.maxParticipants,
    required this.orderIdx,
    required this.productId,
  });

  // Factory constructor to create an instance of Metadata from a Firestore document
  factory Metadata.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Metadata(
      isTestingPlan: data['isTestingPlan'] == 'true',
      maxParticipants: int.parse(data['maxParticipants']),
      orderIdx: data['orderIdx'],
      productId: data['productId'],
    );
  }

  
}

Now, update the StripeProductPlan class to use the Metadata class:
factory StripeProductPlan.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data()!;
    return StripeProductPlan(
      //you can change like this--------
      metaData: Metadata.fromMap(data['metadata'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      selfRef: snapshot.reference,
      name: data['name'] as String,
      role: data['role'] as String? ?? '',
      taxCode: data['taxCode'] as String? ?? '',
    );
  }

